# Consuming a JSON API response using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip

I came out with the following to read the IP of the client connecting to my server. It works fine, however I can read the single "ip" value from the returned data structure. Must be something basic, but I never work with jQuery/Javascript...

```
$.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/json/', function(data) {
  var data = (JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  console.log(data);
  var ip = data['ip'];
  console.log(ip);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just erase the following line

```
var data = (JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

`getJSON` will automatically parse the data for you 
and you don't want to cast your data to string

Consider however to chain with a `.fail()`  in case something goes wrong

Comment: Oh! Yes, perfect, that was it!

Comment: Thanks for the .fail() suggestion too. I'll do it.

Comment: While this fixes the issue, it does not explain the issue.  Yes `getJSON` will auto parse the response, but the OP is not trying to parse it.  They are calling `JSON.stringify()` which will turn an already parsed object *into a string*.  It's not the correct method at all, disregarding the `getJSON` usage.